# I cannot run Windows without connecting the flash drive in which linux was installed

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed Linux into my flashdrive from another flash drive while windows 7 is running. When I start up my computer with the flash drive in which linux installed , it appears 4 options ( Linux, Linux recovery, window , windows recovery ).Linux used to work smoothly but something happened and I could not open linux again. Terminal screen appears but it says there is a problem with system file . But I still get 4 options in start-up and I can open windows 7 if I connect the flash drive.

But the problem is I cannot run Windows without connecting the flash drive in which linux was installed.When I disconnect the flash drive and start up the computer in a usual way, windows logo never appears and black screen appears and it says like " welcome to grub..there is no such a device..recovery mode.."

So how can I run windows directly like in the past? I worry if I lose the flash drive I will not able to run windows either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that GRUB cannot detect windows installed on your system. However, the GRUB on your flash drive can.

In order to fix this, download any recent Ubuntu live medium, then mount the flash drive and hard drive. Now, take a look at the GRUB config file on your flash drive and copy it to your hard drive's GRUB. Make sure you change the values to suit your system, after copying it to your hard drive.